# UITextView Spelling correction is not working some times

Tags: iphone, uitextview, spell-checking

I am implementing spelling correction in my UITextView like this

```
[txtView setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
[txtView setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
```

It is working sometimes but, some times it is not working..

Please suggest me ho wi works.

Comment: looks like nothing wrong and it should work all the times. Can you post the input that it works and the input that it doesn't work?

Comment: it is working fine all times now. no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your UITextView in Story Board.
In Attribute Inspector under "Text View" section find "Correction" and "Spell Checking" and select "Yes" for both.

Don't worry if you don't want to allow Correction. You can switched off "Auto Correction" in your iPhone Device Keyboard Settings.

And make sure you have switched on Check Spelling in Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Check Spelling on your iPhone Device.

Thanks,
Mohsin

Comment: But we should not dependent on iPhone system setting. Like are approaching to each client and tell him to turn of auto-correction from system settings. Who was your lead!